# How to best store tokens in a container?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm rather new to programming and am trying to create a small parser with the spacy package.
What I would like to do would be to parse through any kind of text (as string), and store each word plus its POS-tag. I thought about doing this with a dictionary in which each word is the key and its POS-tag its value so it would look like this:

```
    import spacy
    tokendictionary = {}
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp("I will not regret this, so this is not a regret.")
    for token in doc:
         tokendictionary[token] = token.pos_
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
    {I: 'PRON', will: 'VERB', not: 'PART', regret: 'VERB', this: 'DET', ,: 'PUNCT', so: 'CCONJ', this: 'DET', is: 'AUX', not: 'PART', a: 'DET', regret: 'NOUN', .: 'PUNCT', Do: 'AUX', you: 'PRON', regret: 'VERB', this: 'DET', ?: 'PUNCT'}
```

However, I know I cannot store identical keys, but I need to keep each token stored (like in this example for 'regret', so even if it appears twice or more, it should still be stored individually and should be easily accessible. Which would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Use a list of tuples.

Comment: Your tokens are already stored in a container, called `doc`.  What could be a reason to have another one?